# Prove that the function has derivative for any $x$ from $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: derivatives

$$y= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} e^{2x} & & x \geq 0 \\ x^2+2x+1 & & x<0 \end{array}\right.$$

Prove that the function has derivative for any $x$ from $\mathbb{R}$
I have tried and it turns that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{x}=$ I don't know how to solve it
and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x^2+2x+1-1}{x}=2$. 
How do I solve the first limit so that it equals 2 too?

**We haven't learnt the  L'Hopital's rule yet.**

Comment: Hint: Test the limits of the derivative at 0 from both sides.

Comment: Look into L'Hopital's rule

Comment: @Nitin Is there another way to solve it? We haven't learnt that rule yet

Comment: The derivative of $e^{2x}$ is $2e^{2x}$ while the derivative of $x^2+2x+1$ is $2x+2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{x^2+2x+1-1}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}(x+2)=2$$

For the other side:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{2x}-1}x=(e^{2x})'|_{x=0}=2e^{0}=2$$

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to obtain this result without the use of L'Hopital.

Comment: I realize the OP may have edited to include that fact *after* you posted your answer.  So no fault to you.  Just bringing you up to date.

Comment: @amWhy Hi there...I am *not* using l'H at all: the lower side is **the definition** of the derivative of $\;e^{2x}\;$ at $\;x=0\;$ ...

Comment: @amWhy BTW, both mfl and I did the very same left sided limit at the beginning because in the **original question**, which was very messy, it said, or at least seemed to say, that it was that side the OP didn't succeed to do.

Comment: I realize the confusing question, and don't fault either answer (note I did not, nor anyone else, downvote either answer. In fact I gave you (+).  But part of the inherent risk of jumping the gun in answering a question is the very fact that the OP often needs to clarify, edit, etc.  So my comments are merely informing of an update to the question, which may change the way the answerer may want to answer.

Comment: Besides, the OP seems to have only encountered the definition of the derivative, and correctly wrote $$(e^{2x})' = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{2x}-1}x=(e^{2x})'$$ All you did was to confirm that it indeed, it is equivalent to $(e^{2x})'$

Comment: If the OP hasn't learned how to take a derivative without making use of the definition of the derivative, you've missed the poing.

Comment: Or are you unwilling to or unable to answer how to take the limit: $ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{2x}-1}x$ **without the use of nondefinitional derivatives.?

Comment: @amWhy (1)Correction: if the OP hasn't yet learned derivatives then **he** has missed the point of telling us. (2)The only tag this question has is, precisely, derivatives. Unfortunately, this site's never required, in spite of tens of recommendations, from whoever asks a question to fill some lines about her/his mathematical background. It all is usually a matter of guessing. About how to evaluate that lower limit: I guess it could be evaluated without mentioning derivatives, perhaps with some $\;e^{2x}-1=(e^-1)(e^x+1)\;$ and/or logarithms, etc.  but the tagging seems to imply the OP knows.

Comment: When students are first learning the definition of the derivative, they are very aware that they're engaged with derivatives. So the tag is not surprising. My whole point, all along, has been that answerers should not assume the OP has more knowledge than they've shown. The fact that the OP responded to the original question, using the definition of derivative and hoping to prove the limit... and that fact that s/he has yet covered L'hopital's rule, gives you every reason NOT TO assume the OP is able to find derivatives  without use of the limit definition.  Anyway,  I'm done here, @Antotinio

Answer (score 0):

We have that $f$ is differentiable if $x\ne 0$ and

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2e^{2x} & x>0 \\ 2x+2 & x<0\end{cases}$$ Now, since $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=2$ we conclude that $f$ has derivative at $x=0$ and, moreover, $f'(0)=2.$

Comment: You just proved what the OP already figured out.  The OP is asking how to determine $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{x}$.  Read the question carefully: "$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{x}$ = I don't know how to solve it"...$\;\;$ ...and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x^2+2x+1-1}{x}=2$"

Comment: @amWhy I have misread the question. Thank you for noticing it. I have editted the answer to fix it.